# Linking / Using Google Plus on Gmail with multiple Google Apps domains

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

I started my G+ account on my private Gmail account.

Now G+ is also available for Google Apps (I also have 2 email addresses at other organisations who are using Google Apps).

Ideally I would like to sort of a **link my G+ profile with this 2 email addresses** (so that the people with who I correspond by email can see my photo in email and also to add me to their circles).

Creating new profiles on Google Apps and maintaining them make little sense to me, because I will have to manage multiple accounts under the same name.

Also if somebody searches for my name, getting 3 profiles also does not do me any good.

Comment: TMO, G+ for Google Apps should hold your business info - not your personal info.

Answer (score 1):

Google does give the option for users to link additional accounts. The following information can be found in [Google Support Documents](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=oz&ctx=ch_AddSession&answer=1721977):

**Sign in to multiple accounts at once**

Tired of always signing out to switch between your accounts on your own computer? Whenever you need to switch accounts, just click the **Add account** button to sign in to your other account(s) and conveniently switch between them.

[image: Multiple sign-in does not merge account data, and it does not give one account access to another.]

Multiple sign-in is most convenient to use on devices that you don’t share with other people (where you won’t need to sign out to let others access their own accounts).

**Sign in to additional accounts**

1. Sign in to a supported Google product.
2. Click your name or email address at the top of the page.
3. Select **Add account** from the drop-down menu.
   [image: Account information while signed in to one account]
4. On the page that opens, enter the email address and password for another account you wish to access, and click **Sign in**.
   [image: Screen Shot of Sign In]

**Switch between accounts**

Once you’re signed in to more than one account in the same browser, you can easily switch accounts. Just click your name or email address at the top and click on the email address you’d like to sign in to.

[image: Account information while signed in to two accounts]

**Products that do not support multiple sign-in**

Some Google products and mobile versions of Google products do not support the use of multiple accounts in the same web browser. Instead, they *default to the first account that you signed in to* from your current browser.

If you want to use an account with a product that doesn't support multiple accounts, you have two options:

- Sign out of all your Google Accounts and then sign in to the account
  you want to access.
- Sign in to another account using a second web    browser [Learn more](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=179235).

**Signing out**

If you choose to sign out of any account while using multiple sign-in, you will be signed out of all your accounts. To resume using multiple sign-in, you will need sign in to one account and then use the **Add Account** option to sign in to your other account(s).

Comment: Just a note... If the account that you are linking doesn't support the Google Product you will get a screen letting you know, but you will not get access to the product if that account didn't already have it.

Comment: This doesn't actually link the accounts in any way.  It just lets you be logged in to all of them simultaneously.  But no data, information, or settings are shared among the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional email addresses to your profile but you can't have a G+ profile that accesses multiple gmail mailboxes.  You can transfer G+ Circles to your new G+ account (http://gigaom.com/2012/07/12/google-plus-apps-account-migration-tool/) and then just stop using the old accounts.

I went thought the same thing when G+ for App was created.  I have a (something)@gmail.com G+ account with a profile picture that says, "Go to my other account", and my "real" G+ account is something@(my personal domain) account.

Comment: More details on the transfer process at http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/transfer-google-plus-accounts/.